# How to get logging working with django?

Tags: django, authentication, logging, django-debug-toolbar

I am testing my own auth backend, as descried [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). I have a added some logging. Please obviate these two issues, which are known to me:

- I am using the `root` logger (bad)
- I am using the `error` log level (bad)

(I just want to find out why my log messages are not being shown, and want to make sure I am hitting a working logger / level)

```
import logging

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SettingsBackend:
    """
    Authenticate against the settings ADMIN_LOGIN and ADMIN_PASSWORD.

    Use the login name and a hash of the password. For example:

    ADMIN_LOGIN = 'admin'
    ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'pbkdf2_sha256$30000$Vo0VlMnkR4Bk$qEvtdyZRWTcOsCnI/oQ7fVOu1XAURIZYoOZ3iq8Dr4M='
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        logging.error('authenticate')
        login_valid = (settings.ADMIN_LOGIN == username)
        pwd_valid = check_password(password, settings.ADMIN_PASSWORD)
        logger.error('username={} login_valid={} pwd_valid={}'.format(username, login_valid, pwd_valid))
        if login_valid and pwd_valid:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                # Create a new user. There's no need to set a password
                # because only the password from settings.py is checked.
                user = User(username=username)
                user.is_staff = True
                user.is_superuser = True
                user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        logging.error('get_user')
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        logging.error('has_perm')
        return user_obj.username == settings.ADMIN_LOGIN
```

I have setup this as my only auth backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'extras.auth.SettingsBackend',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

And I have configured my admin user:

```
# Used by SettingsBackend

ADMIN_LOGIN = 'admin'
ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$9pA3fTzM4yL9$whatever'
```

I have lots of problems here:

1. The log entries are not shown, and not intercepted by the django debug toolbar.
2. Authentication does not work at all. Even **forcing** `login_valid = True` and `pwd_valid = True`, I can not get an authenticated user.

I know that the `authenticate` method is hit, because if I rename it, I get an exception (`'SettingsBackend' object has no attribute 'authenticate'`), as expected.

I have two questions:

**First question**: how do I get the log entries to show up? Putting them in the top-level works! As shown here:

```
import logging

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

logging.error('Loading module')

...
```

Which gives me, as expected (once, when the module is loaded):

```
ERROR:root:Loading module
```

**Second question**: why is the `authenticate` method failing? (This is not so important, I guess I will be able to find out what is wrong with it once I get logging working)

Note: for the record, the application is running as `wsgi` app under `gunicorn`.

### EDIT

I am using:

- Django 1.10.8
- Python 3.5.2

Comment: Your `authenticate` method works fine for me in dev (including the logging) with Django 1.11.2 and Python 3.5.2 (btw you have a small typo `logger.error`). Have you tried a regular `print` on your `runserver` in dev?

Comment: @SébastienDeprez thanks for trying it out! Not yet, I will try it early in the morning. I tried with regular `print` calls, but they are not allowed for `wsgi` apps, and i want to keep dev and prod aligned. The typo was not such: I want to actually use `logging.error` and not `logger.error` (actually I am removing the `logger` since it is misleading). I want to use the root logger.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez in dev (with `manage.py runsslserver`) I am not getting it to work, not even with `print` calls. It seems that, although the `authenticate` method is somehow accessed, it is not being *executed*: putting a bad statement `XXX` has no effect.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez I found the problem: the signature of `authenticate` has changed from Django 1.10 -> Django 1.11. I started with Django 1.11, where the authenticate method was working, and at some point I downgraded to Django 1.10 because of other issues. I was not aware of this signature change when doing the downgrade. Now that I am testing this, it is silently failing (not sure why) and it was difficult to understand why.

Comment: Alright, glad you found it! You can probably self answer then to help future readers.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez sure, done! Thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to a downgrade in the Django version, from [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) down to [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). The signature of the `authenticate` method has changed. It was being accessed, but somehow it was not being executed, and the log entries were not being generated.

I do not fully understand why:

1. The `authenticate` method was not being executed. The signature has changed, but it has default values, it should still work (with the wrong values being assigned to the parameters)
2. If something prevented the execution of the `authenticate` method, why was no exception being generated?

Anyway, after adapting the signature to the one expected by Django 1.10, everything started working as expected.